# Implementing Rust generated API in C using Webassembly

Tags: c, rust, webassembly

I have the following problem/task and I don't know how to approach it.

So I have a complex project where Developers can add plugins without changing anything on the system. For this there is a simple API. To develop a plugin, the developer has to implement a trait - this is how it would look like in Rust:

```
// Own struct
struct TestHandler;

impl FileHandler for TestHandler {
    fn new() -> Self {
        TestHandler
    }
    fn parse_files(&self, files: Files) -> Result<ParseFileResponse, Error> {
        Ok(ParseFileResponse {
            files,
            metadata: MetaData { data: Vec::new() },
        })
    }
    fn load_files(&self, files: Files, _meta: MetaData) -> Result<Files, Error> {
        Ok(files)
    }
}

export_file_handler_api!(TestHandler);
```

As I mentioned, the backend supports webassembly. So the task is to not use Rust for the generating a plugin but C. Goal to get a .wasm-binary at the end which implements the filehandler-API and exports the following functions: (C-Signature)

```
// Returns a ptr to a file handler
// The pointer is passed to the other functions
unsigned int new_handler();

// Destructs a file handler construted with new_handler
void destroy_handler(unsigned int);

// Returns a ptr to a result of Files/Error
// Arguments:
// 1. file handler ptr
// 2. ptr to files struct
// 3. ptr to MetaData struct
unsigned int load_files(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int);

// Returns a ptr to a result ParsedFileRespons/Error
// Arguments:
// 1. file handler ptr
// 2. ptr to files struct
unsigned int parse_files(unsigned int, unsigned int);
```

My question would be: How to I approach this task implementing these functions - what do I have to import and how to I handle the pointers to my own struct?

Comment: Have you looked at https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/ffi.html#foreign-function-interface?
You could write those functions as extern "C" in rust directly (and mark the TestHandler as repr(C)). For manipulating pointers you might want to look at std::ptr. If you need to hand out heap objects, Box has `into_raw` and `from_raw` methods to convert to/from pointers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - the work within Rust already has been done like handling pointers and so on. My question is more about how to use this interface inside C I found no example on how to import and use these Rust functions inside C.

Comment: Like for example for the function new_handler() how do I create a "file-handler" within C and return a pointer to it?

Comment: If you write some wrapper functions with `extern "C"` functions and mark them as `#[no_mangle]` in rust, you can just link the C code together with your rust code and C functions can call your rust `extern "C"` functions without issues. Similarly you can declare a C function in rust and can call it from rust functions. See also the ffi link in my previous comment. The rust code could use `Box::into_raw` to create a pointer from a heap variable and pass that to C. But make sure to read the documentation to understand the implications of `into_raw`.